# If I use two negation operators on a string am I using type coercion?

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

Consider the following code:

```
!!('foo');
```

The negation operator uses the abstract operation `ToBoolean` to perform a type conversion, but my question is - does this involve type coercion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion " the word coercion is used to denote an implicit conversion", so yes there is type coercion involved, since the conversion is enforced.

Alo take a look at the answer to this question [What is the difference between casting and coercing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857763/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-and-coercing)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that coercion is simply an `implicit` conversion, that being either a `cast` or any kind of `processed conversion`, than yes, this involves coercion, because you didn't convert it explicitly.

Comment: So type coercion is not a specific feature of JavaScript per se, but a behavior associated with certain operators in JavaScript (and other languages).

Comment: Exactly. Any language can implement coersion. C#, for instance, even allows you to override operators in such a way that you can "control" coercions.

Answer (score 0):

!!(x) appears to return the same result as Boolean(x). You can see this for yourself by typing the following into the JavaScript console:

```
Boolean(false) === !!(false)
Boolean(0) === !!(0)
Boolean("") === !!("")
Boolean(null) === !!(null)
Boolean(undefined) === !!(undefined)
Boolean(NaN) === !!(NaN)
```

All over values are 'truthy' in JavaScript. Haven't checked every other available value in JavaScript; that could take some time. ;-)

Comment: Yes I believe it is equivalent. See 11.4.9 in the spec.