# C# Unclear Syntax in foreach

Tags: c#, list, model-view-controller, lambda

I found this piece of code in a scaffolded view in a C# project, but I don't really understand the syntax after the "List" part. Why do you declare a list of prices before writing ViewBag.data? Because the ViewBag.Data already contains a query with prices converted to a list so I don't understand why that happens

```
@foreach (var x in ((List<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.Price>)ViewBag.data).Where(x => x.ProductId == item.Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).Take(1))
```

that's the complete query, but my question is only about this part:

```
List<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.Price>)ViewBag.data
```

how does this syntax work? Thanks!

Comment: That's not a variable declaration, that's a type cast.

Comment: Yes it is a casting of the property ViewBag.data to the type: List<SomeObject> this should not be a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tells the compiler that `ViewBag.data`, which can be anything since you can put anything you want in a `ViewBag`, is of type `List<WebCashRegister.Models.BLModels.Price>`.

This is an example of an explicit cast:

```
List<object> myList = new List<object>();
MyAunt terry = new MyAunt();
myList.Add(terry);
```

Now if you have a function

```
public void Congratulate(MyAunt somebody)
```

then you cannot just call

```
Congratulate(myList[0]);
```

because the compiler doesn't know that it is the right type. So you have to help the compiler by saying

```
Congratulate((MyAunt) myList[0]);
```

Comment: Your answer should at least mention "type cast"... coercion is an implicit conversion (cast), question refer to an explicit type cast... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857763/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-and-coercing

Comment: In your opinion, sure. I'm just trying to be as helpful as I can. Thankfully there are God characters here with ginormous Stack Overflow scores such as you to set me straight again.

Comment: Either way @dna2 it didn't deserve a down vote, that is just petty.

Comment: If it's all about points, you can be relieved, I've removed the downvote :) If it's just because I've a lower score than yours, I'm sorry I've dare to correct you. For me to remember: http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow

Comment: That's not what that was about, in case you didn't realize that by now.

Comment: Really interesting article, BTW. Michael Richter makes some very good points.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, especially yours Roy! It all makes sense now, and as the others said I looked up type casting which was helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ViewBag` is defined as `dynamic`. Once there's a need to treat it as a `List<Price>` in order to perform some LINQ operations, you have to explicitly cast it to the appropriate (original) type.

See [ViewBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598922.aspx)